# How to use mult-Threads in Eigen‘s cwise operations

Tags: c++, eigen

There are many operations similar to dot multiplication in my code.but it seems that Eigen's cwise operation does not use use mult-Threads.I tried to perform similar operations with openmp, and found that my code was faster than eigen.

````
EIGEN：4.4ms
```
Eigen::setNbThreads(10);         
int n = 2048*2560;     
MatrixXd A = MatrixXd::Ones(1, n);     
MatrixXd B = MatrixXd::Ones(1, n);     
MatrixXd D(1, n);     
clock_t start = clock();     
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)     
{         
    D = A.array() *10 *B.array();
}     
clock_t end = clock();     
double thisTime = (double)(end - start)/1000;     
std::cout << thisTime << std::endl;
```

My:2.607 ms
```
int n = 2048*2560;    
MatrixXd A = MatrixXd::Ones(1, n);     
MatrixXd B = MatrixXd::Ones(1, n);     
MatrixXd D(1, n);     
clock_t start = clock();     
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)     
{ #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(10)         
for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)        
  {             
  D(0, j) = A(0,j) * 10 * B(0, j);         
  }     
}     
clock_t end = clock();     
double thisTime = (double)(end - start)/1000;     
std::cout << thisTime << std::endl;
```
````

How to use mult-Threads in Eigen‘s cwise operations? thanks！

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How to use mult-Threads in Eigen‘s cwise operations

Answer (score 0):

[As the documentation says](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicMultiThreading.html):

> Currently, the following algorithms can make use of multi-threading:
>
> - general dense matrix - matrix products
> - PartialPivLU
> - row-major-sparse * dense vector/matrix products
> - ConjugateGradient with Lower|Upper as the UpLo template parameter.
> - BiCGSTAB with a row-major sparse matrix format.
> - LeastSquaresConjugateGradient

In any other case you have to roll your own parallelization, if desired. Typically you get reasonable results by parallelizing over columns since Eigen uses [column-major matrices](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TopicStorageOrders.html). For reasonable matrix shapes, this allows vectorization within a column and parallelization across columns.

### Side notes

1. Your code is needlessly inefficient by using dynamic matrices for vectors. Consider changing your types from `MatrixXd` to `VectorXd`.
2. It is rarely necessary to specify the number of threads like that, both `Eigen::setNbThreads(10)` and `pragma omp … threads(10)` are not necessary. Normally you just let OpenMP use all available threads (also used by Eigen) and control OpenMP through its [environment variables](https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.0/openmpch6.html) such as `OMP_NUM_THREADS`

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but I tested to traverse the elements of MatrixXd and VectorXd in the same way as in my code. The time seems to be the same.

Comment: @Oct It depends on the operation and also on whether the compiler can deduce at compile time that the number of rows is 1. Vector-vector dot products in particular create specialized code compared to general matrix-matrix products that just happen to be vector-vector at runtime. Eigen spends a lot of template magic to make sure compile time information like fixed number of rows/columns (=1) in vectors gets used. It is reasonable to assume that is on purpose.